# Empty value after insert - WHY?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

I just need another set of eyes to look a this and tell me that I'm not mad.

I've got a simple code to insert a record into a table in database:

```
$dbh = new PDO(CONNECT, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
$sa = $dbh->prepare("insert into audit (n_slm, n_customer_id, n_contract_id, t_country, t_type, dt_tmstmp) values (:slm, :customer, :contract, :country, :type, :tmstmp)");

print_r($audit);

$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setTimestamp($audit['timestamp'] / 1000);

$sa->execute(array(':slm'      => $audit['slm'],
                   ':customer' => $audit['customer'],
                   ':contract' => $audit['contract'],
                   ':country'  => $audit['country'],
                   ':type'     => $audit['type'],
                   ':tmstmp'   => $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
```

Variable `$audit` is populated with results of `json_decode` of a POST value, but it's irrelevant here.

The record is inserted perfectly fine, but the `t_type` field is always empty.  I added `print_r($audit)` - and here's what I get:

```
Array
(
    [timestamp] => 1391513053680
    [customer] => 100307
    [type] => warehouse
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 2
                    [item] => 1024
                )

        )

    [contract] => 16
    [country] => ca
    [slm] => 20
)
```

Clearly, `$audit['type']` is set to `warehouse` - but it's not getting passed to the database somehow.  Moreover, I tried to substitute `$audit['type']` with a hardcoded `warehouse` - with the same result - the value is not saved into the database.  Can anyone see what's happening here?

Comment: Is the datatype in the database correct?

Comment: @YUNOWORK Ha! Double-checked the database - turns out there was a typo in the DDL and instead of `varchar(20)` the column was created as `varchar(0)`.  Good catch!

Comment: No problem, glad that i could help. ;)